# New MS Access Error on Transfer Text

Tags: ms-access, text, export, runtime-error

I have a morning process that runs in an old MS Access database.  One of the processes that runs in VBA code is an export of data to a text file.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Rest Export Specification", "RestExport", "\\xxx\yyy\srest.txt", False, ""
```

Starting last week I am all of sudden getting an error message when the code hits this process.  I am getting `Run-error 3024: Could not find file` each time it hits this query.  the strange thing is that it fails when running in the morning process but if I manually run it I get no errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should look at to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT:

Based on some discussions I have had it seems like they made some sort of permission change to the directory where this is being saved to.  So I need to make a code change to save the file locally and then do a CopyFile to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get this to work. By adding it locally to the c: drive and then copying to the final location, we are bypassing the error.

```
Public Sub Export()

    Dim oFiles As FileSystemObject
    Dim strSource As String
    Dim strDest As String

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Rest Export Specification", "RestExport", "C:temp\srest.txt", False, ""

    'copy file to NAS drive
    strSource = "C:\Temp\srest.txt"
    strDest = "\\xxx\yyy\srest.txt"

    DoCmd.Hourglass True

    Set oFiles = New FileSystemObject
    oFiles.CopyFile strSource, strDest
    Set oFiles = Nothing

    DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```